# Does setting a writer name for a Moo read-only attribute make it read-write?

Tags: perl, attributes, moo

I'm studying Moo and bumped into this basic question.
If I set an accessor or a writer name for a read-only attribute the attribute becomes writable. Do accessors or writers imply that the attribute is writable even if it's set to read-only (is => 'ro')?

Here is the Class code:

```
#!/home/fl/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.26.1/bin/perl
package MooPerson;
use Moo;
use namespace::clean;

has firstname => (
    is     => 'rw',
    reader => 'get_firstname',
    writer => 'set_firstname',
);

has surname => (
    is      => 'ro',
    reader  => 'get_surname',
    writer  => 'set_surname',
);

sub get_fullname {
    my ($self) = @_;
    my $firstname = $self->get_firstname;
    my $surname   = $self->get_surname;
    return "$firstname $surname";
}
1;
```

Object code:

```
#!/home/fl/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.26.1/bin/perl
use lib 'lib';
use MooPerson;
use feature 'say';
use strict;
use warnings;

say "new object person";
my $person = MooPerson->new(
    firstname => 'Homer',
    surname   => 'Simpson',
);

say "person->get_firstname: " . $person->get_firstname();
say "person->get_surname: " . $person->get_surname();

say "\nchange firstname and surname";
$person->set_firstname('Aristotle');
$person->set_surname('Amadopolis');

say "person->get_firstname: " . $person->get_firstname();
say "person->get_surname: " . $person->get_surname();
```

Result:

```
fl@dancertest:~/perltest$ ./firstMoo.pl
new object person
person->get_firstname: Homer
person->get_surname: Simpson

change firstname and surname
person->get_firstname: Aristotle
person->get_surname: Amadopolis
```

The same behavior occurs when I use accessor.
(is => 'ro') only works if I use the auto generated accessor name, in this case "surname".

Is it an intended behavior or a bug?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, because `is` doesn't make anything read-only; it simply creates an accessor.

- `is => 'rw'` is just a shortcut for `accessor => 'attribute_name'`.
- `is => 'ro'` is just a shortcut for `reader => 'attribute_name'`.

If you specify a `writer`, you will be able to write to the attribute, even if you used `is => 'ro'`.

If I want a public reader and a private/protected writer, I use

```
has surname => (
    reader => 'get_surname',
    writer => '_set_surname',
);
```

or

```
has surname => (
    reader => 'surname',
    writer => '_set_surname',
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is intended behavior and not a bug. As soon as you create a writer with `writer => 'set_surname'` the attribute is no longer read-only in the sense that you can now modify it through the writer. If you want a private writer and a public reader you could put an underscore in front of the name of the writer to indicate that it is internal to the class:

```
has surname => (
    is      => 'ro',
    reader  => 'get_surname',
    writer  => '_set_surname',
);
```

Putting an underscore in front of a method name is the common way in Perl to give a hint to the user that an attribute is intended for private use only.

Comment: Thank you, you're totally right. I found this explanation in Moose 'has is' option: "If you need more control over how your accessors are named, you can use the reader, writer and accessor options inherited from Class::MOP::Attribute, however if you use those, you won't need the is option". So Moo seems to work the same way.